# Chrome Console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome

The issues I am having is with my Chrome browser. I am getting an error in the console which is creating problems with my development environment. This error on happens in Chrome and no other browser. Fire Fox, Safari and Opera are all fine without this error. Also I used a different computer here with the same version of Chrome (48) on the same WordPress website and did not get any console errors. This makes me think it is just on my computer and my browser. So the console error is the following:

> Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window':
>   The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1
>   range.
>
> b.mxpnl.net/cs/dca.js?pid=39266&cid=49544_680_:1

I have found that it is making an external call for this script from b.mxpnl.net in the sources section of the inspect developer tools. It does not make this call with any other browser or in Chrome on a different computer, so again this is making me believe it is just on my computer, my Chrome. Could it be a malware or virus?

Comment: You're going to need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: See if that helps: http://www.freefixer.com/b/remove-cdn-mxpnl-com-from-firefox-chrome-and-internet-explorer/ (Found by searching for the domain name of the script you mentioned. Not the exact same subdomain there, but it sounds like mxpnl.com might be the origin of several scripts that might be, if not necessarily harmful, rather not in the user’s best interest. Could be that they have something to do with https://mixpanel.com/, which claims to be a mobile analytics service.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what code to include as I don't think it is my code but the call to the external script that is causing the error. This call to the script only happens on my Chrome and no other browser of laptop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have this error too today, now I found that error is in extension "Responsive Web Design Tester"

Comment: @frosty22 Thanks. I also had "Responsive Web Design Tester". Now that it is disabled the console error is gone. Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We spent all day on this. Turned out to be a extension installed. Disable them and retest.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you. Really Appreciate the effort.